# to give link to the icon before navbar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Sorry if my title is wrong, I can't think of a good title for this problem.
I want is to put a small icon before navbar so that the visitor can goes into another site by clicking in that icon. So, I tried to give that icon in before class of my navbar. Doing so I found that, no links can be given to a before class.

So, is there a way to do as it from js or by changing some styling, It will be very much helpful if it can be.

[you can view what i meant from this link](https://jsfiddle.net/1mtcs757/34/)

```
      <nav class="navbar navbar-blend navbar-default">
        <div class="navbar-header pull-left">
                   
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="http://upper.dev/suisse-japon-final/suissejapon110216/" rel="home" title=" Schweizerisch-Japanische Gesellschaft – www.swiss-japan.ch">
                    <img src="http://2d6t692n0eb7333453op21it.wpengine.netdna-cdn.com/cym/wp-content/themes/30web/assets/img/logo.png" class="img-responsive showinbetween"></a>
                   </div>
                    <div class="navbar-header pull-right">
                      <ul class="nav pull-left">
                       <li class="dropdown pull-right">
                         <div id="lang_sel"><ul><li><a href="#" class="lang_sel_sel icl-de">DE</a> <ul><li class="icl-en"><a href="http://upper.dev/suisse-japon-final/suissejapon110216?lang=en">EN</a></li></ul></li></ul><span class="sj-down-arrow">▾</span></div>                            </li>
                      </ul>
                        <button type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse" class="navbar-toggle"><span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span></button>
                    </div>
                         
               <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-right" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                     <ul id="menu-menu-1" class="nav navbar-nav">
         <li id="menu-item-20" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-menu-item page_item page-item-12 current_page_item menu-item-20"><a href="http://upper.dev/suisse-japon-final/suissejapon110216/">Home</a></li>
              <li id="menu-item-155" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-155">
         <a href="http://upper.dev/suisse-japon-final/suissejapon110216/?page_id=140">About Us</a>
           <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li id="menu-item-175" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-175"><a href="http://upper.dev/suisse-japon-final/suissejapon110216/?page_id=156">Activities</a>
        
        </li>
              <li id="menu-item-527" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-527"><a href="http://upper.dev/suisse-japon-final/suissejapon110216/?page_id=234">Activities</a>
             
         </li>
            <li id="menu-item-231" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-231"><a href="http://upper.dev/suisse-japon-final/suissejapon110216/?page_id=51">Membership</a>

            </li>
             <li id="menu-item-50" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-50"><a href="http://upper.dev/suisse-japon-final/suissejapon110216/?page_id=41">Various</a></li>
             <li id="menu-item-40" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-40"><a href="http://upper.dev/suisse-japon-final/suissejapon110216/?page_id=31">Links</a></li>
              <li id="menu-item-30" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-30"><a href="http://upper.dev/suisse-japon-final/suissejapon110216/?page_id=25">Contact</a></li>
                   </ul>             
                            </div>
                  
            </nav>
```

Sorry for the logo and icon its just for demo.[image: Its like it in full width]
[image: Its in mobile view]

You can see the small icon between navbar and navbar-brand image, I want to put link to that small icon.

Comment: Didn't get your problem. Could you please be more specific?

Comment: you can see the small icon in both image (in large view =  before home menu) (in small view = before language selector) i want o give link to this icon

Comment: Pseudo elements are not part of DOM, so JS and jQuery can't assign a link to them. You need to create DOM  element and link it.

Answer (score 1):

why using a pseudo element before and not an element ?

```
<section id="nav-container">
<a class="nav-country" href="#yourlink"><i class="icon-country"></i></a>
<nav id="main-nav">your navigation here</nav>
</section>
```